# JUnit date-time comparison with uncertainty

Tags: java, datetime, junit, junit4

When checking for double values, it is normal to provide precision (delta) for comparison functions, like in [asserEquals()](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(java.lang.String,%20double,%20double,%20double))

How to do the same for date-time values? Suppose I don't wish to compare with microsecond precision, but wish to check some inexact timings.

How to accomplish that?

Comment: `DateUtils.truncate` (from common-lang) or `d1.getTime() - d2.getTime() < something`?

Comment: The reason you have to do it with double, is because `1.0 / 3.0 * 3.0` may not be exactly 1. There is no such problem with date-time logic, so why would that be needed?

Comment: There IS such problem in date time logic, for example, when measuring time.

Comment: How can a measured time be unit tested? Environmental factors may cause insane fluctuations in response times. Unit tests are for ensuring the *logic* is correct.

Comment: I would like to test namely logic. I have an object, which has timestamps inside. Regard some filesystem file analogy. So, I would like to check, how these timestamps controlled. So I am generating timestamps in test too and compare. Since I can't guarantee exact instances coincidence, I need delta.

Answer (score 6):

If you have Date, you can use the built in error.

```
assertEquals(date1.getTime(), date2.getTime(), 1);
```

If you have a LocalDateTime, you can compare the truncated times.

```
assertEquals(ldt1.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLI_SECONDS),
             ldt2.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLI_SECONDS));
```

Comment: Where is this `assertEquals()` with third parameter?

Comment: @Dims Its this method http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(double,%20double,%20double) which takes a delta.  If there differences is smaller than the delta, it's considered to be equal.

Comment: So, this uses implicit conversion to `double`?

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would just write a simple Hamcrest style Matcher for it...

```
class CloseToDate extends BaseMatcher<Date> {

    private Date closeTo;
    private long deltaInMs;

    public CloseToDate(Date closeTo, long deltaInMs) {
        this.closeTo = closeTo;
        this.deltaInMs = deltaInMs;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object arg0) {

        if (!(arg0 instanceof Date)) {
            return false;
        }

        Date date = (Date)arg0;

        return Math.abs( date.getTime() - closeTo.getTime()) <= deltaInMs;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description arg0) {
        arg0.appendText(String.format("Not more than %s ms from %s", deltaInMs, closeTo));
    }

    public static CloseToDate closeToDate(Date date, long deltaInMs) {
        return new CloseToDate(date, deltaInMs);
    }
}
```

This way you can use static imports to simply write...

```
assertThat( myDate, closeToDate( someDate, 1000 ) ); // for 1000ms tolerance
```

...which is, if you ask me, pretty well readable.

Comment: Might want to do `<=` so a delta of `0` means exact timing. This would be consistent with the `assertEquals` referenced in the question which states "the maximum delta", meaning a value equal to delta is still valid.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. Edited into the answer so that people will not have to search through the comments for it.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert to String using same format (to whatever the precision you want) and compare the two strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/eXparity/hamcrest-date#usage

```
LocalDateTime myAppointment = LocalDateTime.of(2015, AUGUST, 9, 10, 30, 0);
assertThat(LocalDateTime.now(), within(15, MINUTES, myAppointment));
```